# How to intercept PHP function call in my script?

Tags: php, function

I know that I can intercept method call with `__call` magic method for objects. But how I can intercept a PHP function (build in PHP or defined by user) call in my part of script?

For example, I have some code:

```
echo "Hello world";
$s = 0;
$i = $i + 5;
$str = str_repeat('Hi ', $i);
$hash = md5($str);
print $a;
```

I need to intercept `str_repeat()` function call and do not execute it and all code after it and return some error (or simply execute `die('error');`), is it real?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you check this : http://www.java2s.com/Code/Php/Class/InterceptingMethodCallswiththecallMethodPHP5Only.htm ?

It's not complicated but you need to write a bit of code.

You can also create your own intercepting function that takes a callback and instead of calling your function/method you can pass it through your own intercepting function.

**PSEUDO CODE**

```
function myFakeFunction(...){ ... }

function runFunction($functionName){
  // DO WHAT YOU WANT: INTERCEPTION
  call_user_func($functionName);
}
runFunction("myFakeFunction", ...);
```

[call_user_func](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func.php) in docs.

NOTE: you should care about security issues for both methodologies.

EDIT: I just have a new idea, you can also create a shared object for all the methods that you want to check and use _call on that object. But I'm not sure if that would work correctly.

Comment: Thanks very much, I like your idea and I will try to use it in my solution

Comment: You're welcome. Got another idea => combine runFunction with the shared object.

Comment: What do you think, I can to forbid specific functions call with your solution?

Comment: Well it depends how you secure and how you use it. Don't let a user choose a function from $_GET, $_POST or $_REQUEST or from a DB value and I should be fine. This is a very sensible part, in the point of view of security so you should really care and know what you are doing.

Comment: Tell please, what are you think about my example? I add it to my question.

Comment: Well what I would simply do if you only have a single function to observe is creating your own MyStrRepeat('Hi ', $i) which will embed str_repeat from PHP inside of your own function...

Comment: But if I cann't modified this code? For instanse, this code enter some other user, but I need to execute it without `str_repeat`

Comment: This code is a simple PHP string. I can wrap this code with `try catch`, replace some part of it, but user can wrote variable function `$func = 'str_'.'replace'; $func();`, and it passed :(

Comment: it seems a bit complicated. Can you be a bit more precise of the goal you are trying to achieve ? And yes they can replace it with some tricks like concatenation but you can block this by using addslashes for example

Comment: Ok, my goal is a more complex. I need to realize something like PHP sandbox where users can execute any PHP code, intercept disallowed functions like `unlink`, `rmdir`, `file_get_contents`, etc... And I search a solution for a shared hosting, where I cann't get access to `php.ini` config. And explain please, how can I use `addslashes` for this aims?

Comment: So the user write PHP code in a form and you execute PHP code ? right ? If so 1) It's very dangerous 2) you need to have an access to PHP.INI in order to forbid some function (best way is to have a dedicated VPS only for that purpose) 3) there is no magic you will need to cover all the tricks that user can do to avoid your security

Comment: Yes, execute PHP code from form. Ok, thanks very much!