# How to intercept a function call (with arguments) without editing function or the code that calls it?

Tags: php, drupal-7

I want to intercept CMS function and log it's arguments every time it is called. Namely I want to get all calls to [`t()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7). Problem is, in CMS core there are 1875 calls to [`t()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7), so it is not feasible to edit code that calls it. On the other hand, I can include my code snippet before first function call.

I have seen [How to intercept PHP function call in my script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21501605/2389310), but it's accepted answer assumes user can replace direct calls with calls to his new function. That's not my case. Linked article is about intercepting methods, so it seems not applicable, too.

Some of the other Drupal functions, like `variable_set()`, use global arrays, so [I was able to plug into them by replacing global array with an object](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/87177/16495). Sadly, `t()` only uses `global $language`, and this variable is not an array searched against function's argument, so this approach is not possible **and I need a native PHP solution**.

Is there any way to intercept actual function calls, the way they are written? For now I actually hacked [`t()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/t/7), but I really, really want to avoid it. Sadly, all solutions I found on the net seems to cope with interacting with own code, not with the code written by others in framework.

Last but not least: I can install additional software on dev machine. It's Ubuntu Server. So if any PHP plugin can be used, I'd like to know that. I would *prefer* solution that does not require any, but I can live with it.

This question is related to, but not a duplicate of, [How to make strings from templates translatable on all pages they appear?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/121639/16495) on Drupal Answers. Now I'm trying to find a way to hack `function _l10n_client_page_strings()` of [Localization Client](https://www.drupal.org/project/l10n_client) module. But I'm sure actual function call interception would be interesting for many people.

## Why I need it?

To answer [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739764/how-to-intercept-a-function-call-with-arguments-without-editing-function-or-th#comment38380303_24739764): Well, I believe it's generally interesting PHP issue, but my questions has also a practical purpose.

To translate website, one would traditionally:

1. Export translatable strings
2. Translate *.po file without seeing where and how string is used, possibly introducing errors (usually person translating site is not the one who manages it in day-to-day basis, so translator does not *know* the context)
3. Import file
4. Test translation, note errors and things that does not make sense
5. Go to 2.

With [Localization Client](https://www.drupal.org/project/l10n_client) procedure should look like that:

1. See page with untranslated / badly translated strings
2. Fix translations directly

Simpler, faster, less error-prone. Only problem with this module is that it does not collect strings actually used on page, but uses queries that *"will not work reliably"* (their own comment), so:

- it lists a lot of strings, some of them are not really used on page, just happens to be in a module used in page generation
- and worse, it misses some strings.

That's why I was trying to patch `_l10n_client_page_strings()` function with something that works slower, all right, but also is doing it's job directly. And I know some calls in template files may happen too late, but I'm willing to cross that bridge when I'll reach it. For now I need a reliable way to actually know these calls without hacking anything but the module I'm trying to force to work the way it should.

Comment: What exactly is the motive behind that? For example, if you're trying to debug the function, the best answer would be to attach an interactive debugger and set a breakpoint. If you're trying to filter out untranslated strings, the best answer is probably to use a tool to parse your source files to extract all strings (e.g. `xgettext`).

Comment: @deceze Localization Client claims "fix translations on your site as you see the issues". But it does not collect actual string being translated to render the page, it uses black magic and queries that "will not work reliably" (comment in it's own code). So I'm trying to replace guesses with a list of strings that *really* are translated to be seen on the page. I can have all strings extracted all right, but there is a ...load of them and my translators gets lost. And there are translation errors due to lack of context. Making module really do what it claims to do would help significantly.